# CODEC and Resolution in Multi-Variant Master playlist

Tags: ffmpeg, hls

I am recording my content in wowza using cupertino hls (.ts files).

I am building a playlist from these chunks at an interval of 30 mins. But while creating master playlist with all the bitrates, i need to add "CODECS, RESOLUTION".

So finally my playlist should have something like this

> ```
> "#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=250000,CODECS="avc1.77.31,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1280x720"
> ```

How do I get values of codec(h264-main or h264-high)? Will any of the tools like bento4, ffmpeg help me getting the values like (**avc1.77.31,mp4a.40.2 or avc1.66.30,mp4a.40.2**)?

bento4 creates the manifest files when we can use mp4s directly. But I have .ts files directly. So, how do I get the codec values?